# Store & retrieve image into SQLite Database

Tags: android, database, image, sqlite, blob

I'm going to store an image which is in drawable folder into SQlite database and after it, simply retrieve it. I'm going to modify this concept later, but i got nothing in ImageView.

Here is the code:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    protected static final String DATABASE_NAME = "kamuskerul2";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private final Context myContext;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqlitedatabase) {

        sqlitedatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE tableimage (image BLOB);");
        Bitmap mybitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(myContext.getResources(), R.drawable.me);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        mybitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
        byte[] img = bos.toByteArray();

        ContentValues myContentValues = new ContentValues();
        myContentValues.put("imag", img);

        sqlitedatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO tableimage (image) VALUES('"+myContentValues+"');");


    }// END of onCreate().


    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqlitedatabase, int i, int j) { 
        if (i >= j) {
            return;
        } else {
            sqlitedatabase.execSQL("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS kamuskerul2;");
            onCreate(sqlitedatabase);
            return;
        }
     }
  }
```

And the other Class(retrieve the image and display it).

```
private DBHelper dbhelper = new DBHelper(this);
private SQLiteDatabase db;  
ImageView myTestedImageView;
byte[] imgimg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.MainActivity);

    db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();

    // ImageView
    myTestedImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myTestedImageViewXML);

}// end onCreate



public void onClick(View v) {
    String image_name = "myContentValues";
    Cursor cursor_image = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tableimage " + "WHERE image='" + image_name + "';", null);

    if (cursor_image.getCount() != 0) {

            cursor_image.moveToFirst();
            do {
                imgimg =   cursor_image.getBlob(cursor_image.getColumnIndex("image"));
            } while (cursor_image.moveToNext());

            Bitmap b1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgimg, 0, imgimg.length);
            myTestedImageView.setImageBitmap(b1);

}
```

When i run the app nothing display and the db is empty.
Hope you get my idea and help me to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the bytes of the image in a database, it would be better to clone the image to the external storage of your app. You can save the path or just the name of the image in the database.

Android Docs about Storage Options for files in particular: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Saving an image in an SQLite database as a blob is from my point of view bad practice, even if you convert the image into bytes.

Comment: So you know any tutorial which goes step by step to achieve my goal.Somehow i knew to android and need more advise/search. TNX.

Comment: The link in my answer is somewhat a tutorial on how to store an image on the android device. Just get the path of that file and store it in the sqlite database as a string.